# Redirect to a page on manual page refresh using page refresh button or f5

Tags: jquery

I want to redirect user to Google whenever he clicks on the browser page refresh button or press the f5 key

I write this code but it's not working fine:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
        location.href = '<?=$szLinkURL?>';
             return 'are you sure you want to leave?';
}
```

I want that if I choose yes, then only I will be redirected, else stay in the same page.

Also, if only refresh button of the browser is clicked, then only the script will run; it won't run when the back button or forward button will be clicked.

Comment: onbeforeunload will fire ANY time the window is unloading resources to display a new page. There's no distinction between a refresh, back button, forward button, HREF, or just typing a new URL in the address bar.

Comment: Check the following link. that'll help you. On refresh, redirect like following  window.location.replace("url");
http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/45329-How-Detect-browser-address-bar-refresh-Cancel-button-Javascript.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
     window.setTimeout(function () {
                     window.location =<?=$szLinkURL?>;}, 0); 
     window.onbeforeunload = null; 
// necessary to prevent infinite loop, that kills your browser }
```

---